# URLSession cached data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm new in iOS dev and I do not understand one think. So I have gz file and inside gzip there is xml file. I need to download gz file, every time user start the app. First time when I start my app I use this code to get data. Problem is my xml file was offline on server for few day and my app always start without problem and show data with no problem. So all my files was cached on device?. I want my data is retrieved every time while the user start the application. I am not sure do I did something wrong? Thanks

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://sitename/xxx.gz")

    if url != nil {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let nsdata = data as NSData?
                let content = nsdata?.gunzipped()
                let dataContent = content as Data?

                let urlContent = NSString(data: dataContent!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) as NSString!

                let xml = XMLParser()
                xml.getDataforTable(data: urlContent as! String)

                 NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "XmlDataLoaded"), object: nil))

            } else {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "DataNotLoaded"), object: nil))
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Where have you written this piece of code in your project? I mean which file? Move this code in your `AppDelegate`'s `didLaunchWithOptions:` method.

Comment: Which notification got posted?  What happened after the notification?

Comment: I call this in my loading view controller. So I have viewcontroller and in viewdidload I call this function if everything is fine "XmlDataLoaded" notification, I load next viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here
```

in AppDelegate.swift

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

call your web services method inside this method

}